# Storing birthdate in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm just getting started in django, and for practice I'm creating a database that holds "client" objects which stores their first name, last name, email, and date of birth. I've been following the django tutorial and looking at the documentation, but I haven't clearly found exactly what I wanted.

```
from django.db import models

class client(models.Model):

   def __str__(self):
       return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

   first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
   last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
   bday=models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

This is what I have as far as models.py goes. Would this serve my purpose, and even if so, is it the most efficient way to store this information granted I may need to sort by certain days, months, or years.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. Don't worry about performance just yet, but if it becomes an issue, it's easy to add an index.

Comment: Alright, awesome. One last question if that's the case: How exactly would the parameters be written? Suppose I wanna test it in the cmd shell.

Comment: Do you mean to create a new instance? Use keyword arguments, e.g.: `c = client(first_name='...', last_name='...')` etc. The `DateField` expects a `datetime.date` object. You can always create an empty instance and add the values later on.

Comment: Exactly. I'm not sure how to write the parameters when instantiating the object.

Comment: Just like that, `<ModelClass>([<field_name>=<value>, [<field_name>=<value>, [...]]])`. E.g. a client object representing you would be `client(first_name='Jabrill', last_name='Peppahs')`. It would help with readability (especially for anyone trying to help) if you took a look at the [PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @knbk
Well, I'm confused as to what value DateField wants. I put in '     bday= 1996, 4, 3' and it'll return a syntax error.

Comment: Like I said, it expects a `datetime.date` object, i.e.: `import datetime; client(bday=datetime.date(year=..., month=..., day=...))`.

Comment: @JabrillPeppahs If you have got answer for this then please post it as an answer. Thank you